# Body not shown in signed mail message

Tags: c#, email, outlook, exchangewebservices

I have a programm, interpreting the attachement of incoming mails and writing the results of my findings in the body of the received email.

No problem at all so far...the problem comes with mails that are signed. I am able to get the attachements of the signed mail by interpreting the .p7m-File that is attached, and writing into the body of the message like this:

```
emailMessage.Body += string.Format("</br></br>Erste Abweichung ({0} Fahrplan):</br>{1} - {2}", 
           kind, pos.FromTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
           pos.ToTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"));

emailMessage.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);
```

I can see that the body property is set in Visual Studio, but in Outlook I don't see any body text. It works great when the message is not signed.

The problem now is that I don't know if this is a problem with outlook, or if I somehow have to sign the body text that I have created.

Any hint would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the signed/encrypted messages, the body is always extracted from the p7m attachment. PR_BODY, PR_HTML or PR_RTF_COMPRESSED are not used.

Think about it - the whole pointy of signing a message is to prevent anybody from tampering with its contents. That is precisely what you are trying to do.

You can of course turn the signed/encrypted message into a regular message by setting the MessageClass property to "IPM.Note" and extracting the data from the p7m file, but I doubt your users will appreciate that.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will try that. And yes I know what a signed message is used for, and I also know what my users want, so if they want that I change the text of an auto generated mail which will be deleted anyway afterwards, I think its okay to try.